# Sort product attribute terms using WooCommerce wc_get_product_terms function

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I have an eCommerce website powered by WooCommerce. I'm using product variations to allow my customers to choose a specific configuration for their product.

I'm using the following code to list the terms names of a specific product attribute:

```
$available_pa_colors = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_colors' );
```

And it works great.

However **when changing the default sort order** from "Custom ordering" **to "Term ID"**, I get nothing (no term names show up).

I did some research and it seems that wc_get_product_terms won't work with sorting.
 How I can make this terms to get sorted by Term ID?

Any track on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The function [`wc_get_product_terms()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-term-functions.php#L159-L173) uses [`_wc_get_cached_product_terms()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-term-functions.php#L133-L157) **which prioritize stored cached data** against the use of WordPress `wp_get_post_terms()` included in it. 
That's why you can't sort anything.

So instead you should use directly [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) which allows sorting like:

```
$available_pa_colors = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_colors', array(
    'orderby' => 'term_id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'names'
) );
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec ! Just rename wc_get_product_terms() to wp_get_post_terms() and the sorting of attributes on the site changed from the default by Name to the sorting that was set in the product card variations.